# Apache PDFBOXMerge functionality

Tags: merge, sequence, pdfbox

We want to use the Apache PDFBOXMerge functionality - Any idea how the PDF files will be merged - the order. I have 100 page PDF file which belongs to different customers and for each customers they are numbered, page 1 of 5, 2 of 5 and such

Is there a way that we can suggest the order of merge or do we have to hard code the order like C:\f\test1.pdf,C:\f\test2.pdf, C:\f\test3.pdf

Comment: You have to pass them in the order that you want them to be merged. I wonder - what else did you expect?

Comment: thanks,  I was expecting that I can in a sequence with a suffix on the file name .1, .2. .3 and the merger will take care of it

Comment: No, the merger doesn't care about file names. What counts is the sequence in which you pass the files.

Answer (score 1):

Merge functionality doesn't care about file name. If you want to Merge pdf using file name than you can use import functionality.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PDDocument mergeDocument = new PDDocument();
    PDDocument doc = null;

    File dir = new File("folderPath");  //Provide directory path where all files are stored 
    File[] files =  dir.listFiles();

    for(File file: files) {
        doc = PDDocument.load(file); //Load Pdf file

        //Import Page one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            mergeDocument.importPage(doc.getPage(i));  
        }
    }

    // save merged pdf
    mergeDocument.save("location");
    mergeDocument.close();
    doc.close();
}
```

You can get you file list as per your requirements and than import page one by one.

Comment: thanks so much, that will give some flexibility - when  i only need to drop the files in a specific location